# Using LIKE to Get Substrings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, ms-access

How can I use `LIKE` to extract substrings of a `VARCHAR` column?

ie. I have the following records:

```
1: "@D.Test1 some text"
2: "some other text @D.Test3"
3: "text @D.Test1 text"
4: "text @D.Test14 text"
```

Now I want to build a list of unique values matching a pattern.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DoSomethingToExpr(expr) AS output FROM tbl WHERE expr LIKE '%@%'
```

What do I replace `DoSomethingToExpr(expr)` with in order to extract these variable-length matches? I can write a more sophisticated pattern to match the full values, but where can I use that? I don't see any straightforward way to make the actual substring function work well here with each case. My desired output would be something like:

```
1: @D.Test1
2: @D.Test3
3: @D.Test14
```

I'm using both Oracle and MS-Access, so a solution that can be adapted to both is preferable.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MS-Access? Currently, you have both tags.

Comment: @Mureinik: I'm using both. Ideally I will find a solution that works in both (small adjustments to syntax are fine).

Comment: So if you found the index of `@D.` and the index of the first space after that, would that be enough to extract the required string?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Almost, but not quite. Consider my second record.

Comment: OK, so the first space after that or the end of the line.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Yes, that would work fine. I'm not aware of how to find that endpoint using `PATINDEX`.

Comment: I think you want to use CHARINDEX to locate the space; it includes an optional parameter for where to start searching from. If there is only one "@" then you can use CHARINDEX for that too.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks, this is used in p.s.w.g's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but here's a solution using basic string functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
          expr, 
          CHARINDEX( '@', expr ), 
          ISNULL( 
            NULLIF( 
              CHARINDEX( ' ', expr, CHARINDEX( '@', expr ) ), 
              0 ), 
            LEN( expr ) ) 
          - CHARINDEX( '@', expr ) + 1 )
       AS output
FROM   tbl
WHERE  expr LIKE '%@%'
```

Of course, this has some downsides. It expects the `@D.Test…` string to be followed by either a space or the end of the string. If it can be followed by any other character, you'd have to tweak this. However, if you want to do anything more than complicated than this, you might be better off doing this in your application code rather than SQL.

Comment: Interesting use of `NULLIF`. Fortunately, this is as complicated as it gets. I'm going to test this out with the equivalent MS-Access functions.

Comment: @grovesNL I'm glad I could help. Yeah, I admit I'm not that familiar with either MS-Access or Oracle's SQL dialects. There may be better solutions that take advantage of platform-specific features, but I tried to answer this using only the most generic functions I could. Tested on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use Regex in SQL. In SQL you can only test whether a text matches a pattern using wildcards; however, you cannot extract the matching substring in a simple way with these wildcards.

I suggest you to split the logic between the query and the front-end. The query would only test for the existence of "@" for instance, and the front-end would perform a more sophisticated processing on the returned records in VBA or whatever language you are using.

Comment: I see your point, but I was hoping to perform this inside a sub-query, so that's why I didn't split this logic initially.